# A Frame Image displaying flat

Tags: html, augmented-reality, qr-code, aframe, markers

I am trying to use  and  to track a marker used in a QR code, and when the marker is captured on the camera it shows an image on top. My code is able to recognise the marker and display the image, but the image is flatten and it only shows a thin line, even though I have set width and height to 4 (meters). Below is my source code and a screenshot of how the image is currently displaying on the camera. I have circled in red the line that corresponds to the image on camera.

```
<!-- we add detectionMode and matrixCodeType to tell AR.js to recognize barcode markers -->
<a-scene embedded="" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false; detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3;">

<a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="animated-asset" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicolocarpignoli/nicolocarpignoli.github.io/master/ar-playground/models/CesiumMan.gltf"></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>

<a-marker type="barcode" value="7">
    <a-image src="https://ewouk.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/cropped-Screen-Shot-2020-04-10-at-12.48.46-pm.png" width="4" height="4"></a-image>
</a-marker>

<a-marker id="animated-marker" type="barcode" value="6">
    <a-entity animation-mixer="" gltf-model="#animated-asset" scale="2 2 2">
    </a-entity>
</a-marker>

<a-entity camera=""></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to rotate the image (something like `<a-image rotation="90 0 0" ...)`.